# How can I read the specific field of a object in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently stuck at reading data that comes from imported async function.
Here is my async function that gets doc from users collection based on currently logged user,then it gets cart field which is array,next there is forEach that's pushing doc.data() object into array and lastly it returns that array:

```
export async function readUserCartData(userId){
  const userSnap = await getDoc(doc(db,"users",userId));
  let cartItemsData=[];
  if (userSnap.exists()){
    let productIdArray = userSnap.data().cart;
    productIdArray.forEach(product => {
      let q = query(productsColRef,where('__name__','==',product));
      onSnapshot(q,(snapshot)=>{
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc =>{
          cartItemsData.push(doc.data());
        });
      });
      
    });

    return cartItemsData;
  }else{
    return Promise.reject(Error(`No such document: ${coll}.${id}`));
  }
    
}
```

And here i'm handling this function:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth,(user)=>{
  if(user){
    userId = user.uid;
    console.log(userId);
   // readUserData(userId);
    readDocumentById("users",userId).then(data=>{
      userData = data;
      DisplayDeliveryAddress(userData.address.street,userData.address.city,userData.address.postCode);

    });

  readUserCartData(userId).then(data=>{
    console.log(`typeof(data):${typeof(data)}`);
    console.log(data);
    
    
  });
  }
});
```

[image: logs]

I can't do anything with it. I tried `data = Array(data);` with `console.log(data[0].price);` but it shows "undefined". I guess there is a problem with `readUserCartData` but i can't find any solution.

Comment: Where are you trying this `data = Array(data);` because in your code you can only access `data` property inside the `then` callback

Comment: i'm doing it on data inside ```then```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should do the trick (untested). Do not use the `onSnaphot` method which sets a listener to the query but use the promises returned by the several `getDocs` method calls to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```js
export async function readUserCartData(userId) {
  const userSnap = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", userId));
  let cartItemsData = [];
  if (userSnap.exists()) {
    let productIdArray = userSnap.data().cart;

    const promises = [];

    productIdArray.forEach((product) => {
      let q = query(productsColRef, where("__name__", "==", product));
      promises.push(getDocs(q));
    });

    const arrayOfQuerySnapshots = await Promise.all(promises);

    arrayOfQuerySnapshots.forEach((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        cartItemsData.push(doc.data());
      });
    });

    return cartItemsData;
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(Error(`No such document: ${coll}.${id}`));
  }
}
```